# body element having two background colors

Tags: css, vue.js

I gave body element red value background-color with class binding and on styling I set it white color. The only thing I want is to control the background color with my vue, but it's not at full height.

```js
export default {
    data(){
        return{
             text : 'Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse voluptatibus dolores rerum excepturi corporis nisi odit minus earum adipisci non laboriosam deserunt autem architecto molestias, explicabo provident laborum omnis accusantium!',
        
             author:'',
             backgroundcolor:'#16a085',
        }
    
    
    },
```

```css
html, 
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color:white;
}

.background{
    background-color: red
}

#wrapper{
   
    width: 650px ;
    min-height: auto;   
    background-color: rgb(198, 241, 200);
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 200px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.btn{
    position: relative;
    
    left:6px;
    margin: 10px;
    
}
#text{
    
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:30px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
#icon{
    font-size:35px;
    margin:5px;
    padding-top:20px;
}
#twitter{
    background-color: rgb( 0, 172, 237)
}
#author{
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    left :400px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
   
 <body :class="{ background: backgroundcolor }"> 
<div id='wrapper'>  
      <p id="text"><i id='icon' class="fas fa-quote-left"> {{text}}</i></p>
       <span id='author'>- {{author}}</span>
       <button id='twitter' class="btn"><i class='fab fa-twitter'></i></button>
       <button  v-on:click="changeWidth()" @click="start " class="btn btn-success">New Quote</button>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay if you want the background to have the color red then just add the class plainly this way,

```
<body class="background"> 
.background {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    }
```

This is what I have understood from what you have tried to question?
If you could explain more specifically what you require then I think I can help you out more?
Or instead add the add the same in the 
    'html,body{}'
styling instead of a seperate class.

Comment: can you take a look at the image ..i want to display the background color of the body element at full height but its following the height of the child div elemnt height thanks

Comment: i tried that but still same probleme as the image i included

Comment: have you tried changing the white background? Maybe make it blue and make use of inspect element to check where the flaws are? I feel removing the 'auto' from the 'min-height' will solve the problem.

Comment: one thing i tried is to set the height of the first div child at 100% and it worked but i dont want it like that ....i want the box at taht specific height

Comment: yes @lafeo_007 i tried that but same ..whatever color i make it will take that white color area only

Comment: I suggest remove the auto margin from the #wrapper and make the body 100% height while having a specific height for the wrapper?

Comment: Alright do you have sometime? I am not home yet. I'll reach in an hour or so. It'll be awesome if someone else replies to you and clears your doubt otherwise I'll do the same on my laptop and will surely help you out? Is that cool?

Comment: yeah sure  thanks in advance :) i tried removing that auto margin but still same thing

Comment: Also the way you have imported the classes in the body (in your html code) is peculiar try importing the class the way I showed. It's easier and fool proof. If it still doesn't work then just wait I'll reach home and let you know is that cool?

Comment: Try simply typing either background in the classes or remove the class altogether and style the body tag itself! @SirDad you getting me?

Comment: yes bro the was i imported the class is same as you did its just vue bind command to asign the class if the elemnt background exist ()

Comment: i dont want to remove the class because i want it to manipulate the backgroud color with vue (i want to change it with a botton click)

Comment: heyy im sorry i have been off for a while, did it work? it been like a year!

Answer (score 0):

You are pulling your body down because you have set a margin-top on the wrapper. To deal with this, just wrap it in another div which takes a padding. Also make your body 100%. 
Take a look at following fiddle:

```
body: {height: 100%}
```

https://codepen.io/nielsvhb/pen/oQLZVQ